# Cannot rm or cp files with a wildcard in name

Tags: bash, quoting, wildcards

I have a line like this in my script:

```
rm "$TEMP_DIR/*.txt"
```

It fails with this output:

```
rm: cannot remove 'temp/*.txt': No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why doesn't that work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Because you're using quotes in the command, `rm` thinks you want a filename with a literal `*` character, it's not expanding that as a wildcard. Try it without the quotes to match all files ending with `.txt` instead:

```
rm "$TEMP_DIR"/*.txt
```